# Broken Clock vs Normal Clock

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm trying to prepare for an interview and have looked at this problem:

There's a broken clock and a normal clock. The broken clock moves "rate" seconds each second, while the normal clock moves a standard one second per second. Both clocks start at 12:00:00, and AM/PM don't matter (as in, 01:23:15pm == 01:23:15am). Given "rate" and $X$ number of hours, how many times is the broken and normal clock at the same time over $X$ hours? "Rate" and $X$ can both be decimals, and "Rate" can also be negative.

I know how to solve this problem if "rate" and X are both integers (for each second, brokentime = (brokentime + rate) mod 43200 since there are 43200 seconds in a half day and AM/PM is not important), but how would I go about doing this if they were both decimals? I'm having trouble figuring out a formula.

Comment: By a negative rate you mean that all the hands of the clock move in an anticlockwise direction?

Comment: Do not deface and delete the post after you received an answer. That is considered rude.

Comment: Lewis Carroll said that a clock that has stopped is more accurate than one which  loses a minute a day because it it perfectly accurate twice a day, while the other one is hardly ever right. :)

Comment: Lewis Carroll is my hero. Mentioning him always gets upvoted.

Comment: If the rate is irrational, they will never again show the same time. Later edit: This is just wrong :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I believe you are wrong. If the clock has an irrational rate then it will show the real time sometimes. The two hands will lie upon each other at a time which is a fraction of a second. See my interactions with below my answer.

Comment: mathguy gave quite an explanationi. This assumes the idealized clocks' hands move continuously, not in discrete one-second jumps. With discrete jumps, the problem would be quite interesting, since the hands are NOT MOVING for periods of one second at a time, then they jump... entirely different setup! @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Yup. I was thinking about something else. Like continuously moving hands, but only examined at "real" time integer multiple of seconds. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

We will take the case of seconds throughout the answer.

Let us understand what exactly 'rate' is. 'rate' is the time which is changed in the broken clock while it takes 1 second in the normal clock.

So let us define another variable difference. Difference is the difference in time shown by the clocks after 1 second when they both are set to the same time. Difference can be negative or positive. We can also define difference as $1 - r$ where $r$ is the rate.

For example, let in both the clocks the time be exactly 12 and rate of the broken clock be 2. $d= 1 - r = 1 - 2 = -1$ where $d$ is the difference. So after one second, the time in normal clock is $12:00:01$ while in the broken clock is $12:00:02$.
After two seconds, the time will be $12:00:02$ in the normal one and $12:00:04$ in the broken one.

Now let $d_t$ be the difference in time of the two clocks after $t$ seconds.

Now a simple question. When are the two clocks equal? Simple answer. When the time they show is equal on a 12-hour clock. When is the time on a 12-hour clock equal? It is when $c_1 \equiv c_2 \pmod{43200}$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the time shown by the two clocks.

So we want to find the length of the set $\{ d_t | d_t = 0 \text{ and }0 < t < X\cdot 60 \cdot 60\}$.

Also understand one thing. If the two clocks have the same time $n$ seconds from the start, they next time when they are equal will always be $n+n$ seconds.

Now let us find the time $t$ when $d_t = 0 \pmod{43200}$.

$$d_t = d \cdot t \implies d \cdot t = 0 \pmod{43200}$$

Now you have the value of $d$. Find the lowest positive $t$ which such that $d \cdot t$ is a multiple of $43200$. Now you have the value of $t$. 
What is left is easy. You have to find

$$\huge\lfloor\normalsize\frac{X \cdot 60 \cdot 60}{t}\huge\rfloor$$

The two 'brackets' on the side symbolize floor division. It means that you have to leave the fractional part of the answer and stick to the integer.

Example:
When broken clock is literally broken and $r = 0$ and $X = 12$:

$$d = 1 \implies t = 43200 \implies \huge\lfloor\normalsize\frac{X \cdot 60 \cdot 60}{t}\huge\rfloor \normalsize = 1$$

which is true. You may verify it for other numbers.

Hope you found that useful.

Comment: doesn't this equation not hold if rate = 1? Then d will always = 0 and there will be no t to satisfy the equation?

Comment: $0$ is considered a multiple of every number. So you may choose $t=1$ and then the answer will be $43200$ which is the answer. The two clocks will show the same time all the $43200$ seconds. If you have any other queries feel free to ask.

Comment: I suggest you try them on your own and if you find a problem, contact me. And don't forget you can accept and upvote the answer. ;)

Comment: "*could you try these examples: (r = -1, X = 17) and (r = 4.66, X = 50.25)*" this looks very like a *do my homework* query...

Comment: @dhrvu (responding to hey012983): that is definitely incorrect. If the rate is 1 that means the "broken" clock is not broken at all. In that case, the two clocks ALWAYS coincide (every fraction of every second forever).

Comment: @mathguy If you look at it that way it's correct but here we cannot consider division by 0. If you take $t=0$ which is right then the answer would be infinity and you would be right as well.

Comment: @mathguy Another problem is if I choose $t$ as a nonnegative integer instead of a positive one you'll find that $t$ always happens to be 0.

Comment: @mathguy Sorry?

Comment: I am sorry Dhruv, I wanted to post something, got it wrong, had to run so I deleted it - here it is, fixed. Where you say "$t$ is the least positive integer for which $d\cdot t$ is a multiple of $43200$" - that is incorrect. (For $d$ irrational, if $t$ was restricted to integers, $d\cdot t$ will never be a multiple of any integer.) Rather, FOR $d>0$, $t$ is the least POSITIVE number such that $d \cdot t$ is a multiple of $43200$. That $t$ is obviously $\frac {43200} d$. For negative $d$, a very similar argument shows $t = -\frac {43200} d$.

Comment: So - if "rate" = 1 then the clocks always show the same time. If not, the very general answer is (canceling out a factor of $60 \cdot 60$): number of times the clocks coincide = $\lceil\frac {|X \cdot (r -1)|} {12} \rceil$ where $r$ is the "rate".

Comment: @mathguy $t$ is obviously $43200/d$. You're wrong here. Consider $d=13$. Report your results. And Yes $t$ is always positive. If $d$ is negative, $-d|43200$.

Comment: @mathguy You can't form $d$ and $t$ into an equation. Also, if $d|43200$ then $-d|43200$. You have to apply simple divisibility rules.

Comment: Dhruv - $d$ is rate - 1 (or 1 - rate in your notation); $d$ could be $\sqrt 2$. How is $d=13$ a counterexample to something I said FOR IRRATIONAL $d$?

Comment: @mathguy It isn't an counterexample for irrationals but it is for the formula you formed that $t=43200/d$.

Comment: @mathguy I am not able to think of a solution for irrational $d$. Do you have a idea?

Comment: You are thinking about it the wrong way. Time $t$ doesn't have to be an integer! Only $d \cdot t$ has to be an integer, and in fact a multiple of 43200. What I wrote is correct and complete (still your solution though!)

Comment: @mathguy OK! I realize the mistake. So, $t=43200/d$. My approach would have been right if we only wanted the hands to meet at a particular integer second. It wouldn't work if they showed the same time between seconds like the time $12:00:01.500$. Thanks.

Comment: correct... this assumes the idealized cloks' hands move continuously, not in discrete one-second jumps. With discrete jumps, the problem would be quite interesting, since the hands are NOT MOVING for periods of one second at a time, then they jump... entirely different setup!

Comment: Yes. I've made the changes.